# Telnet library for J2ME

Tags: java, blackberry, java-me, telnet

Like the title says. Is there any telnet library that can be used with J2ME?

EDIT: more specifically, I need this library to be used in a BlackBerry app.

Answer (score 0):

one of many:

http://commons.apache.org/net/index.html

Comment: Isn't commons-net always using java.net.Socket for TCP communication, which requires J2SE?

Comment: indeed. sorry, i didn't notice the question was for J2ME.

Answer (score 0):

It's not very clear what you're looking for when you say Telnet library.

The project BBSSH  (http://bbssh.org) is an open source SSH and Telnet client for BlackBerry which contains a telnet protocol implementation.

Specifically if you're looking for something that can handle the telnet protocol itself, these files will be of interest:

- http://svn.bbssh.org/trunk/BBSSH_Common/src/org/bbssh/telnet/TelnetProtocolHandler.java
- http://svn.bbssh.org/trunk/BBSSH_Common/src/org/bbssh/net/session/Session.java
- http://svn.bbssh.org/trunk/BBSSH_Common/src/org/bbssh/net/session/TelnetSession.java
- http://svn.bbssh.org/trunk/BBSSH_Common/src/org/bbssh/net/session/SessionIOHandler.java